# Why the function do not get the dynamic array? (I am using pointers and references)

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

I am learning about dynamic arrays and I get this error:

> invalid types 'int int ' for array subscript

I do not know if my error is passing the array or using the pointers. because if I print the array in the "capt" function the program runs correctly but I want to learn to use dynamic array and use this like as an argument.

```
/*Dynamic Arrays without global variables*/

#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;


/*Function's prototype*/
void capt(int*, int*); //get variables for ref. and use pointers
void show(int, int);   //Only get variabless

int main(){
    int nc=0, calf;

    capt(&nc,&calf);
    show(calf,nc);  


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
/*Functions*/
void capt(int* nc, int *calf){
    cout<<"Digite el numero de calificaciones:"; cin>>*nc;
    system("cls");
    calf = new int [*nc];

    for(int i=0;i<*nc;i++){
        cout<<"Ingrese la nota "<<i+1<<": "; cin>>calf[i];
    }
}

void show(int calf, int nc){
    system("cls");
    cout<<".: Notas del usuario :."<<endl;
    cout<<"Asignaturas evaluadas: "<<nc<<endl;


    for(int i=0;i<nc;i++){
        fflush(stdin);
        cout<<"Nota "<<i+1<<": "<<*calf[i]<<endl; //<---Error Here
    }
}
```

Comment: `calf = new int [*nc];` reassigns the *local* pointer, it does not modify the passed in parameter. Also in C++ you should prefer using `std::vector` and pass by reference instead of passing a pointer (whenever possible)

Comment: it is okay, i am new therefore i didn't know about {std::vector}, im going to read about this for be most efficient working with arrays. thanks =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are messing it up. Here

```
void show(int calf, int nc){
```

then here

```
cout<<"Nota "<<i+1<<": "<<*calf[i]<<endl; //<---Error Here
```

As you can see in the first snippet `calf` is an integer, then on the second snippet you are accessing it using array index (you also have an unnecessary * dereference operation).

Also this:

```
calf = new int [*nc];
```

makes a local variable `calf` to point to a new memory address, it doesn't affect original variable; even if it did though the original variable `calf` is an `int` so you are again messing up here.

---

I think what you are after is something like this (try to read what is *reference to a pointer* in C++ to understand the changes I made):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;


/*Function's prototype*/
void capt(int* nc, int *&calf); //get variables for ref. and use pointers
void show(int*, int);   //Only get variabless

int main(){
    int nc=0;
    int *calf;

    capt(&nc,calf);
    show(calf,nc);  


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
/*Functions*/
void capt(int* nc, int *&calf){
    cout<<"Digite el numero de calificaciones:"; cin>>*nc;
    system("cls");
    calf = new int [*nc];

    for(int i=0;i<*nc;i++){
        cout<<"Ingrese la nota "<<i+1<<": "; cin>>calf[i];
    }
}

void show(int *calf, int nc){
    system("cls");
    cout<<".: Notas del usuario :."<<endl;
    cout<<"Asignaturas evaluadas: "<<nc<<endl;


    for(int i=0;i<nc;i++){
        fflush(stdin);
        cout<<"Nota "<<i+1<<": "<<calf[i]<<endl;  
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh okay I got it, i going to read about {reference to pointers} my error was theoretical, i didn't know about this topic. thanks the program is running correctly =).

Comment: @JavierGámezBojórquez or just first understand what is *reference* type in C++ then reference to a pointer. good luck.